# On Access report, text box in header pulls from form, but only shows up on the first page

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access report in which the user chooses a month from a form, and it runs the report based on the parameter. I have a text box in my report that pulls the selection they made so that my report will show it. However, it only shows up on the first page. Every page after that says #Name?. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Most certainly, but without more details we cannot tell. What is the controlsource of the textbox? Can you add a link to a screenshot of design view of the report?

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/143623642@N05/shares/588uo0

Comment: The controlsource is a textbox in a form.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/143623642@N05/shares/01ka2P

Comment: It's the large textbox on the right of ProviderNumber Header? What is the full control source? (`=[Forms]![ProvCo...`)

Comment: =[Forms]![ProvCoverShtPara]![Text1]

Comment: That is funky. For a test: if you copy that textbox into the Page header and/or the Details section, does it work there?

Comment: Can you share a (stripped down) copy of your database that still shows the issue? I'm kinda out of ideas, except "this should work".